# C++ Compilation error when using typedef'ed members of another class

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, forward-declaration

What is wrong with the following code.
I am getting compilation errors.
I have also tried forward declaration of class B. But could not succeed.

**Test.cpp**

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

namespace api
{

class A
{
public: 
    typedef std::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
    APtr get_a_ptr();    
    B::BPtr get_b_ptr();
};

class B
{
public:    
    typedef std::shared_ptr<B> BPtr;
    BPtr get_b_ptr();
    A::APtr get_a_ptr();
};

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
namespace api
{
  class B; // forward declaration

  class A
  {
    public: 
      typedef std::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
      APtr get_a_ptr();    
      std::shared_ptr<B> get_b_ptr();
  };
  ...
}
```

The problem is that you are requesting something from class `B` that hasn't been defined yet. So use `std::shared_ptr<B>` and you are going to be fine.

---

For more, read: [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: But why can't i use typedef of class B's shared_ptr in class A ?

Comment: I just updated my answer with the answer to that comment @aditya1811. Because a forward declaration says that a class `B` is going to follow, I promise Mr. Compiler, but no way the compiler knows what class `B` will have inside it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that `B::BPtr` is not declared before class A declaration. Your should declare `BPtr` before use it. For example:

```
class B;
class A;

typedef std::shared_ptr<B> BPtr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> APtr;


class A
{
public: 
    APtr get_a_ptr();    
    BPtr get_b_ptr();
};

class B
{
public:    
    BPtr get_b_ptr();
    APtr get_a_ptr();
};
```

Remember that you can not use `operator*` and `operator->` with `shared_ptr` before full class declaration.

Comment: Of course that would be a solution too. Should have covered that, bravo!

Comment: I don't like typedefs for shared_ptr, so in practice I chose your answer (=